# How exchanges manage their wallets for users, and where can i find info regarding

Tags: exchanges

I am developing a platform where average users can easily trade Cryptocurrency. 
I would like to know how exchanges are managing wallets. where they provide a depositing address to each user for each coin.

I have spoken with BitGo and they provide wallet management service for FinTech startups. But they only support

1. BTC
2. ETH (not all other ERC20 Token)
3. LTC
4. XRP

I would like to be able to receive other coins, such as

- TRX
- ADA
- OMG
- and other coins.

Where can i find the info that states which coins are supported by which wallet such as ERC20 or NEO or etc.

Thanks,